# Drop-down containing blocks

Tags: blocks

I am working on building a new site in Drupal 7 and would like to have accessibility options.  I'm using the [Page Style](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagestyle) and [Text Size](https://www.drupal.org/project/textsize) modules, which provide blocks that contain the accessibility options.  However, instead of placing these blocks directly on the site I would like to have them contained in a drop-down similar to the [Perkins.org](http://perkins.org/) website.

Comment: so what is the question?  what have you tried? what research have you done? what worked, what didn't?

Comment: I have the modules installed, enabled, and configured.  I'm just not sure how to get the blocks to be displayed in a drop-down.  Not sure if using a drop-down menu modules is the correct way to do this.  I've searched online and didn't seem to find a specific "preferred" method.

Comment: Can you EDIT you question to include more details a bou the ".. contained in a drop-down similar..."? I looked at the link (I just added that), but still I don't quite understand what exactly you are trying to achieve ... FYI: I'm looking at it from a mobile device ...

Comment: By drop down do you mean menu? In that case look at mega menus.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens don't worry, it's just as confusing on a desktop.  cbuggs: there are different types of dropdowns on that page which act and need to be rendered differently, you need to provide more information about exactly what you trying to do - try explaining it from a user's perspective: user goes to site, clicks on ???, A happens, causing B, to show C, etc.

Comment: Hm, happy to see I'm not the only one who doesn't understand the question entirely. Out of curiousity I also checked on a desktop now, and same result (as @Geoff mentioned). However, after I followed the link to http://perkins.org/library, I did find some type of "drop-down" menu labeled "In this section". So 'maybe' that is the drop-down this question is about? To avoid guessing (as part of a potential answer), I think it's best to wait for a more accurate question now.

Comment: Apparently you didn't really read the post.  I specifically said I'm looking at the ACCESSIBILITY OPTIONS drop-down, which is located on the left at the top of the page.